# published Blazor server app does not provide css in wwwroot folder on linux

Tags: asp.net, linux, blazor-server-side

I have a blazor server app that I want to run on a raspberry pi. So far it is all good, I installed it as a service and the service is running like it should. I published the solution to `srv/myApp` and I have a .service config for it. The only thing missing is the serving of the `wwwroot` folder. When I open the app all the styles are missing. I have `UseStaticFiles()` enabled. When I run it locally or just build the project with `dotnet run` I get the styles from `wwwroot`. The `wwwroot` folder does exist in the published folder, though. It somehow just does not make it to my browser. I wanted to avoid running everything in nginx or something as I want to use the self hosting features.

Does anybody see what I am missing here? This is the project, if someone wants to take a look: https://github.com/modmoto/Deploynator

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i finally found my issue, not all too firm with services on linux. What was missing was the following entry in my service file:

`WorkingDirectory=/srv/Deploynator`

So my complete .service file looks like this now:

```
[Unit]
Description=Deploynator service

[Service]
Type=notify
ExecStart=/srv/Deploynator/Deploynator
SyslogIdentifier=Deploynator
WorkingDirectory=/srv/Deploynator

User=pi

Environment=DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/dotnet
Environment="ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5000/"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Hope that this helps someone some day =)

Comment: Hey! This sounds exactly like my problem.. i'm not sure if I've created a .service file or how to do so if not. I ran the standard dotnet new blazorserver command to create the solution but i still have the issue. Do you have any ideas or anywhere you can point me to? TIA.

Comment: I'm planning on just running this locally now for reference.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a program such as Supervisor to drive your service, be sure to set the working directory

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31491500)